# GridView event raise unexpectedly after postback

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Consider this Asp.net page code:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showhide(master, detail) {
            var src = $(master).children()[0].src;
            if (src.endsWith("plus.png"))
                src = src.replace('plus.png', 'minus.png');
            else
                src = src.replace('minus.png', 'plus.png');

            $(master).children()[0].src = src;

            $(detail).slideToggle("normal");
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDsCustomers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Northwind %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Customers].[CustomerID], [Customers].[CompanyName], COUNT([OrderID]) TotalOrders&#13;&#10;FROM [Customers] INNER JOIN [Orders] ON [Customers].[CustomerID]=[Orders].[CustomerID]&#13;&#10;Group By [Customers].[CustomerID], [Customers].[CompanyName]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" ID="gvCustomers" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataSourceID="sqlDsCustomers" runat="server" ShowHeader="False" OnRowCreated="gvCustomers_RowCreated">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="group" id='<%#String.Format("customer{0}",Container.DataItemIndex) %>'
                        onclick='showhide(<%#String.Format("\"#customer{0}\"",Container.DataItemIndex) %>,<%#String.Format("\"#order{0}\"",Container.DataItemIndex) %>)'>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgCollapsible" CssClass="first" ImageUrl="~/Assets/img/plus.png"
                            Style="margin-right: 5px;" runat="server" /><span class="header">
                                <%#Eval("CustomerID")%>
                                :
                                <%#Eval("CompanyName")%>
                                (<%#Eval("TotalOrders")%>Orders) </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id='<%#String.Format("order{0}",Container.DataItemIndex) %>' class="order">
                        <asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="grid" ID="ddd" runat="server"
                            ShowHeader="true" EnableViewState="false">
                            <RowStyle CssClass="row" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrow" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="rownum">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order ID" DataField="OrderID" ItemStyle-Width="80px" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Ordered" DataField="OrderDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                                    ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Required" DataField="RequiredDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                                    ItemStyle-Width="110px" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Freight" DataField="Freight" DataFormatString="{0:c}"
                                    ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Shipped" DataField="ShippedDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                                    ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</form>
```

and the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void gvCustomers_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string custID = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["CustomerID"].ToString();
        using (DataClassesDataContext dc=new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            List<Order> ord = (from o in dc.Orders
                               where o.CustomerID == custID.Trim()
                               select o).ToList();


            GridView ctrl = e.Row.FindControl("ddd") as GridView;
            ctrl.DataSource = ord;
        }
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

the problem is when I Click on Button1 to redirect to another page `gvCustomers_RowCreated` raise and I get Null reference error.Why this event raised after postback?

---

**EDIT 1):**

I removed SqlDataSource and bind GridView in the code behind like this:

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext dc=new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            var query = dc.ExecuteQuery<clsRetern>("SELECT [Customers].[CustomerID], [Customers].[CompanyName], COUNT([OrderID]) TotalOrders FROM [Customers] INNER JOIN [Orders] ON [Customers].[CustomerID]=[Orders].[CustomerID] Group By [Customers].[CustomerID], [Customers].[CompanyName]").ToList();

            List<clsRetern> ret = new List<clsRetern>();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                clsRetern r = new clsRetern();
                r.CompanyName = item.CompanyName;
                r.CustomerID = item.CustomerID;
                r.TotalOrders = item.TotalOrders;

                ret.Add(r);
            }

            gvCustomers.DataSource = ret;
            gvCustomers.DataBind();        
        }
    }
}
protected void gvCustomers_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string custID = ((clsRetern)e.Row.DataItem).CustomerID.Trim();
        using (DataClassesDataContext dc=new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            List<Order> ord = (from o in dc.Orders
                               where o.CustomerID == custID.Trim()
                               select o).ToList();


            GridView ctrl = e.Row.FindControl("ddd") as GridView;
            ctrl.DataSource = ord;
        }
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx",true);
}
}

public class clsRetern
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
   public int TotalOrders { get; set; }
}
```

I tried `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");` but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand ASP.NET page model then this question should not come to you. Every time request goes to ASP.NET page, a new page object is created along with entire control tree and the state is managed using view-state in post-back scenarios. So in your case, whenever post-back happens, a new page and grid-view is created. The data for the gid-view would be persisted in thew view-state and grid would be bound to that data.

The `RowCreated` event is raised whenever grid row is created regardless of whether `DataBind` is explicitly called or not. The intent of the event is so that one can tweak with UI (grid-view cells) - e.g. some controls can be pushed into grid-view cells if required. The same should happen regardless of post-back scenario other wise those dynamic controls will not get created. Typically, these controls will restore their state using view-state and your get your grid-view UI (control tree) back as it was in first page cycle.

Comment: Please see my edit 1,If I bind gridview in `if(!IsPostBack)` and when postback occures my gridview should not regenerate

Comment: @Nima, as I explained, even if you don't call `DataBind` explicitly on grid-view in post-back, it will still use view-state to restore its state (and that involve creating rows). All ASP.NET data-bound controls follows this idea so that you don't have to rebind them in post-back scenario. You should try disabling the view-state for both grid-view and sql-data-source - that will ensure that your grid-view is not re-generated.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because even if you fire `Response.Redirect`, the `Page_Load` event would still be raised and if your `GridView` binding code is not inside `!IsPostBack`, that code will be hit.

Try this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //bind gridview here
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
    }
}
```

Savvy?

Comment: Iwant to know why gridview row created event must raise after every postback

Answer (score 0):

Add EnableViewState=False to the page directive to prevent "RowCreated" running on every post back.